# Regex for matching mobile topup codes and Url

Tags: java, android, regex

I've been trying to get the start and end position of string from a sentence using Matcher Class . so far I have wrote the following regex for finding the following strings:

```
^\*[0-9].*#$          =>  *1111# 
^#[0-9].*[0-9]$       =>  *1111
^[0-9].*[0-9]$        =>  11111 
^(http:|https:).*[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*$    =>     http://google.com
```

this works fine when a single word is entered but not when i try to find those words in a sentence by combining the regex like this,

**Combined Regex**

```
^(\*[0-9].*#|#[0-9].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[0-9]|(http:|https:).*[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]*)$
```

I  don't know what i'm doing wrong and i assume there should be a better way for implementing this.

**The Code**

```
 SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(ThatSentence);
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.  
            compile("^.*(\\*[0-9].*#s|#[0-9].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[0-9]|(http:|https:).*[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\\-=\\[\\]{};':\"\\\\|,.<>\\/?]*).*$")
            .matcher(spanString); //combined regex

    while (matcher.find())
    {
        System.out.println("lrkjer hurray found something!");
        spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#0000FF"))
                , matcher.start(), matcher.end(), 0);
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {


            }
            @Override
            public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
                super.updateDrawState(ds);

            }
        };
        spanString.setSpan(clickableSpan, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
```

this is used in android , the found string gets clickable by using ClickableSpan Class.

**Examlple String**

```
recharge code is *1111# topup code is *1111 customer care number is +18900657765  and find the details at http://blahblah.com/details
```

Comment: what is the valid and invalid string for the last RegEx?

Comment: preferably,it should find most urls on average.

Comment: can you also post your code so we can look how you are using Matcher?

Comment: @user7854100 I mean combined RegEx

Comment: @PabloEscobar added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is not sound at all. Why it cannot match as expected? You assert beginning and the end position before each alternation. Try it like this:

```
(\*[0-9]+#|\*[0-9]+(?= )|\+[0-9]+|(?:http:|https:)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]+)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/lz6dRA/1)